# Prove a set is countable

Tags: elementary-set-theory

> Prove the set $A = \{n+m\sqrt{2} | n,m\in\mathbb{Z}\}$ is countable

So I guess I need to find an injection for $A$ into a countable set, but I don't seem to get anywhere. Any hints?

Comment: Hint: Take the countable set to be $\{(n,m)\mid n,m\in\mathbb{Z}\}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define $f\colon A\to\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}$ by $f(n+m\sqrt{2})=(n,m)$. This is one possible injection, and, since $\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}$ is countable, it follows that $A$ is countable.